# How Query and Count entries in a Realm Database

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm

I'd like to build a search on which the user can filter down the results step-by-step. So with no choice set, there is a button which says e.g. "1,234,567 Results" and if you choose a color for example the results set shrinks... we all know this kind of search. I did build it many times, but this is the first time in Realm (and swift).

Lets Say I have 5 Persons in my Person Table, then there are about 145,224 Dog entries per Person and about 2,507,327 Cat entries per Dog. How do I query and Count nested Objects in Realm?

```
class Person: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    let dogs = List<Dog>()
    // ...other Properties
}

extension Person {
    static func all(in realm: Realm = try! Realm()) -> Results<Person> {
        return realm.objects(Person.self)
    }
}

// counts -> 145,224 db entries per person
class Dog: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var Person: Person?
    let cats = List<Cats>()
    // ...other Properties as well
}

extension Dog {
    static func all(in realm: Realm = try! Realm()) -> Results<Dog> {
        return realm.objects(Dog.self)
    }
}

// counts -> 2,507,327 db entries per dogs
class Cat: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var Cat: Cat?
}

extension Cat {
    static func all(in realm: Realm = try! Realm()) -> Results<Cat> {
        return realm.objects(Cat.self)
    }
}


// Get the default Realm
let realm = try! Realm()

// Query Realm for all dogs
let dogs = Person.all(in: realm).flatMap { $0.dogs }
dogs.count // => takes ~20 seconds to count
```

In other words, what is the fastest way to get (count) all Dog entries of all Persons (let the cats by side for now).

I tried to workaround the problem by limit the results to 1000. If the results are >1000, then label the button like so "> 1000 Results". But even than it takes very long (I guess the get all count anyway).

So what did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to get a dog count for just those 5 people or all the dogs in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They way you were computing the count required all `Dog` objects to be loaded into memory which is really inefficient. This is why you were seeing such poor performance. You want to take advantage of Realm's lazy loading features. You may want to read up on that.

I would update your `Dog` object by getting rid of your managed `Person` property and replace it with LinkingObjects. If you store a `Dog` in a `Person.dogs` List, then realm will create a back link to the `Person` for you. You will likely want to do the same thing with `Cat`. That way you can set up some really powerful nested queries.

For convenience you can add a computed `Person` property to index into the `LinkingObjects`. Just know that you won't be able to use that property in any of your queries.

```
class Dog: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    let persons = LinkingObjects(fromType: Person.self, property: "dogs")
    var person: Person? { persons.first }
}
```

One way to compute the count is to query of all `Person` objects and sum the count of `dogs` for each `Person`.

```
let count = realm.objects(Person.self).reduce(0) { result, person in
    return result + person.dogs.count
}
```

Another options is to query for `Dog` objects that have a corresponding `Person`. If a `Dog` is not in a `Person.dogs` List, then it won't show up the query.

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let count = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("persons.@count > 0").count
```

Either option is going to be much, much more efficient than what you had.

Hope this helps.